# How can I animate the creation of a new row in NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am having trouble figuring out how to animate the addition of a new row in NSOutlineView.  I have an addButton on each row and when the user clicks the addButton I want a new row to appear below the record the user just clicked on.

My code is creating a new core data record when the user clicks and I would normally just call [NSOutlineView reloadData] and be done - which works fine, just does not look as elegant.

So somewhere I found this method for inserting a row in an outlineView

```
[_outlineView insertItemsAtIndexes:ix inParent:parent withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationSlideDown];
```

Some questions:

1. I can't find any documentation in the SDK explaining this, so if anyone has a link please post it.
2. It seems it is not possible to insert a row below the last row using this method anyway.  Is there another way to add a row to the end of the section in the outlineView with animation?
3. What is the sequence of calls required to a) add a record to the model, and then b) correctly animate the insertion or addition of this record.  Currently the animation inserts a row using the existing rows label, I would prefer it use the object that has been inserted in the models name.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet below may help:

```
outlineView.beginUpdates()
section.children.append(child)
let index = section.children.count - 1
let indexSet = NSIndexSet(index: index)
print("Index of inserted item: \(index) - IndexSet: \(indexSet)")
outlineView.insertItemsAtIndexes(indexSet, inParent: section, withAnimation: .SlideDown)
outlineView.endUpdates()
outlineView.expandItem(section)
```